# Why can't I change my pip3 from the built in to the MacPort-version?

Tags: python, macos, pip, macports

Here is a terminal session:

```
db@air ~ % port select --list pip3               
Available versions for pip3:
    none
    pip3-apple (active)
    pip311
db@air ~ % sudo port select --set pip3 pip311    
Selecting 'pip311' for 'pip3' succeeded. 'pip311' is now active.
db@air ~ % port select --list pip3           
Available versions for pip3:
    none
    pip3-apple
    pip311 (active)
db@air ~ % which pip3
/Users/db/Library/Python/3.9/bin/pip3
db@air ~ % which -a pip3
/Users/db/Library/Python/3.9/bin/pip3
/opt/local/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
db@air ~ % echo $PATH
/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/bin:/Users/db/Library/Python/3.9/bin:/Users/db/Library/Python/3.8/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

As you can see I have two `pip3` installed. Changing from the built in to MacPorts is successful (no error message) and the listing is updated accordingly, but `which` still says that `pip3` points to the built in from Python 3.9 rather than Python 3.11.

What is going on here? How do I make pip from Python 3.11 the "active" one?

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to python3.11 on Friday. After installing python3.11 and python3.11-pip, I checked with:

```
python3.11 -m pip --version
```

That should tell you what version of pip to use.

Then I could run:

```
pip3.11 install ./dependencies/python-packages/*.whl
```

Did you run

```
db@air ~ % port select --list pip311
```

Comment: Yes I did run that. It might be an issue with the order directories were added to the $PATH.